# gcc error compiling file

Tags: c, gcc

```
[user@user Book]$ gcc -o notesearch.c notesearch
notesearch: In function `__x86.get_pc_thunk.bx':
(.text+0x30): multiple definition of `__x86.get_pc_thunk.bx'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.2/../../../crti.o:(.gnu.linkonce.t.__x86.get_pc_thunk.bx+0x0): first defined here
notesearch: In function `_fini':
(.fini+0x0): multiple definition of `_fini'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.2/../../../crti.o:(.fini+0x0): first defined here
notesearch: In function `data_start':
(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `__data_start'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.2/../../../crt1.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
notesearch: In function `data_start':
(.data+0x4): multiple definition of `__dso_handle'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.2/crtbegin.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
notesearch:(.rodata+0x4): multiple definition of `_IO_stdin_used'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.2/../../../crt1.o:(.rodata.cst4+0x0): first defined here
notesearch: In function `_start':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `_start'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.2/../../../crt1.o:(.text+0x0): first defined here
notesearch:(.rodata+0x0): multiple definition of `_fp_hw'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.2/../../../crt1.o:(.rodata+0x0): first defined here
notesearch: In function `_init':
(.init+0x0): multiple definition of `_init'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.2/../../../crti.o:(.init+0x0): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.2/crtend.o:(.tm_clone_table+0x0): multiple definition of `__TMC_END__'
notesearch:(.data+0x8): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: warning: Cannot create .eh_frame_hdr section, --eh-frame-hdr ignored.
/usr/bin/ld: error in notesearch(.eh_frame); no .eh_frame_hdr table will be created.
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
[user@user Book]$
```

I am trying to compile notesearch.c from the book "hacking the art of exploitation" and I get an error. I remember being able to do it just fine. I am on a x86 3.16.7.4-1-MANJARO Linux computer.

Comment: You should instead try `gcc -o notesearch notesearch.c` ! Please don't break conventions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to say `gcc -o notesearch notesearch.c`.  Otherwise, you are OUTPUTTING (`-o`) to the .c file, which is not good.  Also, you may want to consider compiling with these other flags:

`-Wall`: Warn All, very useful.
`-Werror`: Again, very useful.
`-g`: This is my favorite flag.  It compiles with debug symbols, so that you can start you program in `gdb` (Gnu DeBugger) and then examine what is happening, change values of variables during execution, and generally debug it.  `gdb` is VERY helpful.